# Symfony | Entity override

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, overriding

I'm coding an Symfony app composed by a core and some plugins. Each plugin is designed as a bundle and I try to create a system to enable / disable a plugin dynamically (like Wordpress). In a plugin, we can create any type of file (entity, controller, form, etc), and each file could be either for a new feature or for overriding a core's original one. (For example, a plugin could add a birthday field in the User's entity.)

In this context, I have a problem to handle entity files override. The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping) say it's only possible with Mapped Superclasses. However, Mapped Supperclasses [cannot be the targetEntity in associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) and, of course, I have a lot of associations in my app. I also thought about traits but they have [limitations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#using-traits-in-entity-classes) as well, and it would suppose to dynamically add / remove the "use trait" lines in the entity files depending on plugin activation... Looks quite ugly.

So, basically, I'm looking for another way to extend entities but I can't see how to do that properly. How could I do ?

Comment: Use PHP code parser, read in PHP code, change as you like it, output new code, similar to what `make:entity` does

Comment: I would look into using the [MakerBundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle) in some way. If you could get it to work in one command line then that could be your bridge. Also, you could probably reference the migration file so you can use the up and down methods for when a plugin gets added or deleted. Just throwing ideas..

Comment: Be aware that Symfony simply does not support dynamic plugins out of the box.  It is in fact a very challenging thing to implement because of the way Symfony `compiles` its code.  You got much bigger problems than just the entities to look forward to.  Might be better to look at Drupal/Shopware and see how they do things.